# How to add custom Header to Stream Feed Activity?

Tags: getstream-io

I am use React Native component for render feed activity. But I not want display user name on Activity header. I want instead display user bio. How I can do this?

This example code I have:

```
const CustomActivity = (props) => {
  return (
    <Activity
      {...props}
      Footer={
        <LikeButton {...props} />
      }
    />
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
        <StreamApp
            apiKey={key}
            appId={id}
            token={token}
        >
          <FlatFeed Activity={CustomActivity} />
        </StreamApp>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just like you added a footer in the custom activity you can specify a content and header too. So to add a custom header do this:

```
const CustomActivity = (props) => {
  return (
    <Activity
      {...props}
      Header={
        <View>
          {/* Add in bio here */}
        </View>
      }
      Footer={
        <LikeButton {...props} />
      }
    />
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
        <StreamApp
            apiKey={key}
            appId={id}
            token={token}
        >
          <FlatFeed Activity={CustomActivity} />
        </StreamApp>
  );
};

export default App;
```